# HTML convert text into a link

Tags: javascript, html, parsing, dom

I have this html code:

```
<h2>A</h2>
<span>
    <p>Compare BookA. 12:2; BookB. 41:4; 44:6; BookC. 1:11,17; 2:8.</p>
</span>
```

And this JavaScript:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
    window.onload=function(){
        var span = document.querySelector('span');

        txt = span.innerHTML;

        txt = txt.replace(/(BookA)\. ([\d:,; -]+)/g, function (match, book, verses) {
            var link = '';
            verses.split(/;\s+/).forEach(function (elem) {
                if(elem.length > 0) // <== Alytrem's Solution
                    link += '<a>' + book + ' ' + elem + '</a> ';
            });
            return link;
        });
        span.innerHTML = txt;
    }//]]>
</script>
```

I use this to produce what I want:

```
txt = txt.replace(/(BookA|BookB|BookC)\. ([\d:,; -]+)/g, function (match, book, verses)
```

But it returns like:

```
<a>BookA 12:2</a> <a>BookA</a> <a>BookB 41:4</a> <a>BookB 44:6</a> <a>BookB</a> <a>BookC 1:11,17</a> <a>BookC 2:8</a>
```

When I tried this:

```
txt = txt.replace(/(BookA)\. ([\d:,; -]+)/g, function (match, book, verses)
```

It returns like below:

```
Compare <a>BookA. 12:2</a> <a>BookA</a> BookB. 41:4; 44:6; BookC. 1:11,17; 2:8.
```

What I want to get is somethings like:

```
Compare <a>BookA. 12:2</a> <a>BookB. 41:4</a> <a>BookB. 44:6</a> <a>BookC. 1:11,17</a> <a>BookC. 2:8</a>
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

---

**UPDATE**

Thanks to Alytrem's Solution. But I still have a problem, suppose that there is a number before the verse:

```
txt = txt.replace(/(1 BookA|2 BookA|BookB)\. ([\d:,; -]+)/g, function (match, book, verses)
```

And I have this kind of words:

```
1 BookA 15:3; 2 BookA 11:20-22
```

It will returns like:

```
<a>1 BookA 15:3</a> <a>1 BookA 2</a> BookA 11:20-22
```

Comment: I think you want to use [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll) instead of [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelector).. With document.querySelector you will get only the first match...

Comment: @fernandosavio: Hey thanks, but it doesn't work..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because

```
"12:2; ".split(/;\s+/) gives you ["12:2",""].
```

This is your solution :

```
txt.replace(/(BookA|BookB|BookC)\. ([\d:,; -]+)/g, function (match, book, verses) {
    var link = '';
    verses.split(/;\s+/).forEach(function (elem) {
        if(elem.length > 0) // <== solution
        link += '<a>' + book + ' ' + elem + '</a> ';
    });
    return link;
});
```

Comment: Hey thanks! It's work, but there is an issue. Please see the update code above.